# Center the second row in the available screen in the flutter

Tags: flutter

I have `SingleChildScrollView` which has 1 column and 2 row. I want 2nd row content to be the center of the screen(available space).

If I don't have `SingleChildScrollView`, I can just use `Expanded` but here I can't since it will infinite scroll.

So how can we do this??

Here is the source code and expected image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Testing'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: Text('First row'),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      child: Text('Second row'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Expected Image: [image]

Comment: If you want it to be centered, why would you want the Column to be scrollable?

Comment: In some cases there will be multiple rows

Comment: If there are multiple rows, what happens to the item that was supposed to be centered? Which item is it? If there are different layout cases, then it might be worth to make a conditional layouting based on the cases

Comment: Yes, It is conditional.

Comment: The requirement you want does not make sense, how can a widget that is supposed to be placed relative to the screen be inside a scrollable? The solution would not be available in any front-end framework, and as I figure out, what you need is a conditional checking that the scrollable must not be used if the column is below a certain height or having a certain number of items

Answer (score 0):

Check the [answer](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c1a2a4cf389467f6c693cdf3995c21ca) here. You have to set a fixed height for your column for it. Take note on MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top, if you need to get the height of Android status bar.

Comment: I want dynamic answer, Let's say the text inside the first row is variable length.

Comment: @starboy_jb https://iwgtfy.com/?q=Flutter%3A+assign+the+text+inside+the+first+row+with+the+value+of+a+variable%27s+length

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Testing'),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
          height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(   
                  constraints: constraints,
                  
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            child: const Text('First row'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            child: const Text('Second row'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```